# jQuery flot load x-axis from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a jQuery flot graph that loads the x-axis like so:

```
xaxis: {
  tickColor: 'transparent',
  tickDecimals: 0,
  ticks: ticks
},
```

If I set the ticks variable like so it works, and the x-axis contains the 7 dates:

```
var ticks = [[1,"27/07"],[2,"28/07"],[3,"29/07"],[4,"30/07"],[5,"31/07"],[6,"01/08"],[7,"02/08"]];
console.log(ticks);
```

[image: working]

However if I generate the variable from an array like so:

```
var ticks = JSON.stringify(myArray);
console.log(ticks);
```

It doesn't work, the x-axis contains the numbers 1 - 7.

[image: not working]

Here is what the console.log shows:

[image: console]

It looks like my JSON.stringify is correct but I'm not sure what to do! Any ideas?  Why is the first console.log entry coloured but the second one not? Is the format incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `JSON.stringify` turns an object into a JSON string. That's why it's not coloured; it's just a string. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` turns json into a string, but you want an object, so you should use `JSON.parse` instead. `JSON.stringify` is to create a JSON string out of an object/array.

See [this question](http://SON.stringify%20is%20to%20create%20a%20JSON%20string%20out%20of%20an%20object/array.).

Comment: Thanks! I actually had to do this for some reason: `var ticks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));` Not sure why but it works!

Comment: You're welcome. If `myArray` is actually an array, and not json, then you should just be able to do `var ticks = myArray;`. If it is json, then I'm not sure why you had to do that either, but I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Oh god you're right.  `var ticks = myArray;` worked fine! I thought I read somewhere that it had to be JSON.  Well, it works so I'm happy.  Still learning.